# Problems compiling Gforth on Mac

Tags: forth, gforth

I downloaded [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth) 0.7.0 from the official website, placing the folder in `/Applications` and put its alias in `/usr/local/bin`.
After compiling using:

```
$ sudo -s
$ ./configure
$ make
```

When [making](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), it gets the result:

```
cd engine && make gforth-ditc-noll OPT=-noll OPTDEFINES= OPTOBJECTS=dblsub.o
cd .. && CONFIG_FILES=stamp-h CONFIG_HEADERS=engine/config.h ./config.status
config.status: creating stamp-h
config.status: creating engine/config.h
config.status: engine/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing stamp-h commands
echo timestamp > stamp-h
cp -p engine/gforth-ditc-noll gforth-ditc
true
cd engine && make gforth-itc-noll OPT=-noll OPTDEFINES= OPTOBJECTS=dblsub.o
make[1]: `gforth-itc-noll' is up to date.
cp -p engine/gforth-itc-noll gforth-itc
true
./preforth -p ".:~+:." -e 's" mach16b.fs"' ./kernel/main.fs -e "save-cross kernl16b.fi- /usr/local/bin/gforth-0.7.0 bye"


Segmentation fault: 11.
make: *** [kernl16b.fi-] Error 139
bash-3.2# ./preforth


Segmentation fault: 11.
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. I tried  [the answer to Stack Overflow question *Compiling Gforth without Gforth?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384366/compiling-gforth-without-gforth), but it didn't work either. I'm running Mac OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion) on a [MacBook Air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air).

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I solved it. I simply used Homebrew and did a

```
brew install gforth
```

and it worked! It freaking worked! I can't believe I didn't think of that after 2 days of trying...

Comment: it is not the same as compiling it by yourself. "Brewing" gives you the very last version? Getting executable things is usually easier and ok, but nonetheless this won't help anyone: the reason why you get seg fault will be "hidden" somewhere and could affect any other person trying to get gforth compiled and not "brewed"...

Comment: The problem with gforth is a chicken-and-egg one : you need a working previous version of gforth (like a bootstrap) in order to compile a new version. In your initial attempt at compiling gforth, the *bootstrap* (i.e. preforth) was obviously not meant to work on your system, hence the segfault. So yes, one needs to "brew" before compiling ;)